# Changing text on dyamically generated links

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have some link elements which are dynamically added and hidden from the page.

They are generated by a third party telerik control.

I want to change the name of the text, and unfortunately the only way is to use jquery.

I have generated the rule (selector) that catches the Edit links when they are shown. But on initial page load no edit links will be visible. After the user clicks something, these links will be created. After the user clicks something else, these will hide, some other links will show. These are the links I need to change the text on.

How can I write jquery code so that whenever an element matching that selector is added to the page, the button text is updated ?

Thank you!

**Edit0**

I have no control over how they are generated.

There are two grids, parent at top, child at bottom. Initially child is hidden. A row is selected in the top grid, the bottom grid shows items for that selection. This is the point at which these links are added to the page (asynchronously via AJAX), so they are not in the DOM (edit links for each child item in the child grid).

Hope that makes more sense.

**Edit1**

```
//catches the links
$("#CustomClass .t-button.t-grid-edit").text("Awesome text instead of Edit");
```

Comment: "After the user clicks something, these links will be created." - Are you in control of the code behind this? Or do you have no control over the content being added and how it is added?

Comment: I'm confused.  when does this element with said selector get added to the page?

Comment: This question is a bit hard to understand. Do you have any code to show? Like the one to catch the links. Anyway, when you say that the links are generated, are they generated when the page is loaded or are they generated trough an asynchronous call like AJAX?

Comment: Without seeing your code you could use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.7+, you need to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to assign event handlers to current and future DOM elements that meet your selector criteria.

If you're using earlier versions of jQuery, you should use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

You state that you don't have control over how they are generated, but do you have control over adding the content to the page?  If so, you could use custom events (perhaps) and the use of on/delegate to handle the new items being added to your grid.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating this -- http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/xLvYE/

Again, not sure if this helps.  I'll delete if I'm not understanding this correctly.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: `on` is associated with events though. And there is no 'element has been added' event in jQuery. Well, there is `load`, but that is only for elements with a src attribute like img, link, etc.

Comment: "After the user clicks something, these links will be created. After the user clicks something else, these will hide, some other links will show." It sounds like there are at least two click events you could be binding to.

Comment: @skybondsor It does sound like that.  I'm not exactly sure what the code looks like, which is why I put a simple example together.  If that's the right direction, then I think the questioner could run with it.

Comment: This is great help and also I completely skimmed over the idea of two click events I could be binding to, duh! thanks!